# Omitting results containing '//' from grep searches

Tags: grep

I'm trying to search a substantial C++ codebase for a single line that is outputing text to the terminal that I'd like to suppress. I have grepped for `std::cout` and have had around 40 different files returned. The problems I face are:

- I did not add this myself so I have no idea where it is.
- It is a pointer only outputing memory location so I have no context in which to search for it.
- The codebase is enourmous and contains a great many other instances of `sdt::cout` that have once been used for debugging purposes and have since been commented out.

My question pertains to the last one. I am using

```
grep -rle 'std::cout' .
```

to search, which will return positive for instances of `std::cout`, `//std::cout`, `// std::cout` and any other occurence of `std::cout` sitting on a line that is actually commented out.

How can I modify my `grep` to omit any line containing `//` so I can eliminate the commented lines?

Comment: This might solve your problem, without `-l`: `grep -re 'std::cout' | grep -v '//'`.

Comment: From your description, it looks like you wouldn't want to match this line: `std::cout << p; // just debug data`

Comment: "The codebase is enourmous and contains a great many other instances of `sdt::cout` that have once been used for debugging purposes and have since been commented out." This is why you create a separate function for logging debugs and use a define to enable/disable it.

Answer (score 3):

You could look for `std::cout` only when it isn't preceded by `//`. Regexp syntax does not include negation; every regexp can be negated by writing out its complement, but the complement can grow huge. Here, it's not too big:

```
grep -rl -E '^/?([^/]/?)*std::cout' .
```

You can also list all occurrences of `std::cout` and filter away the occurrences of `//.*std::cout`, but note that this will hide things like `std::cout << foo; // std::cout << bar;`.

```
grep -r 'std::cout' . | grep -vE '^[^:]*:.*//.*std::cout' | sed -e 's/:.*//'
```

Alternatively, you can run a tool that parses the C++ code, such as [ctags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctags).

Answer (score 1):

```
egrep -r '^([^/]/?)*std::cout' .
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -r 'std::cout' . | grep -v '^[ \t]*//'
```

will only omit the commented out lines, and not all the lines that have a comment on them.

Comment: `-l` suppresses normal output, so you'd just filter _filenames_ containing comments.

Answer (score 0):

Supplementing [Gilles' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21868/135943), **for a single file** you can just do the whole thing in Sed with much greater simplicity:

```
sed -n 'h;s|//.*||;/std::cout/{g;p;}' file.c
```

In other words, just save (`h`old) the line, strip any trailing comment, then if the line matches the pattern you want, `g`et the saved copy of the line and print it.

For recursive grep, though, use Gille's solution.